# Object returns null

Tags: java, object, null

**Summary:**
New to Java, tried looking through other posts but didn't find an answer. I'm learning inheritance and have an AddressBook class extended by a Runner class. When I write a program to test the inheritance I create a Runner object. If I get the first String parameter it returns fine but when I attempt to get the second String parameter it returns null.

**Question:**
Why is the second parameter returning null?

```html
package Assignment_1;

//Begin Class Definition

public class AddressBook { 

// Member variables
 
 private String businessPhone;
 private String cellPhone;
 private String facebookId;
 private String firstName;
 private String homeAddress;
 private String homePhone;
 private String lastName;
 private String middleName;
 private String personalWebSite;
 private String skypeId;

//Constructors
 
 public AddressBook (String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String homeAddress, String businessPhone, String homePhone, String cellPhone, String skypeId, String facebookId, String personalWebSite) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.middleName = middleName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
  this.businessPhone = businessPhone;
  this.homePhone = homePhone;
  this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
  this.skypeId = skypeId;
  this.facebookId = facebookId;
  this.personalWebSite = personalWebSite;
 }
 
 public AddressBook (String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }
 
 public AddressBook(String firstName, String middleName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.middleName = middleName;
 }
 
 public AddressBook (String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.middleName = middleName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }
 
// Getters and setters
 
 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }
 
 public String getMiddleName() {
  return middleName;
 }
  
 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }
   
 public String getHomeAddress() {
  return homeAddress;
 }
 public String getBusinessPhone() {
  return businessPhone;
 }
 
 public String getHomePhone() {
  return homePhone;
 }
 
 public String getCellPhone() {
  return cellPhone;
 }
 
 public String getSkypeId() {
  return skypeId;
 }
 
 public String getFacebookId() {
  return facebookId;
 }
 
 public String getPersonalWebsite() {
  return personalWebSite;
 }
 
 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }
 
 public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
  this.middleName = middleName;
 }
 
 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }
  
 public void setHomeAddress(String homeAddress) {
  this.homeAddress = homeAddress;  
 }
   
 public void setBusinessPhone(String businessPhone) {
  this.businessPhone = businessPhone;
 }
 
 public void setHomePhone(String homePhone) {
  this.homePhone = homePhone;
 }
   
 public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) {
  this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
 }
  
 public void setSkypeId(String skypeId) {
  this.skypeId = skypeId;
 }
  
 public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
  this.facebookId = facebookId;
 }
 
 public void setPersonalWebSite(String personalWebSite) {
  this.personalWebSite = personalWebSite;
 }
  
 // Public methods
 
 public static void compareNames(String name1, String name2) {
  
  if(name1.equals(name2)) {
   System.out.println(name1);
   System.out.println(name2);
   System.out.println("The names are the same.");
  } else {
   System.out.println(name1);
   System.out.println(name2);
   System.out.println("The names appear to be different.");
  }
  
 } 
  
************************************************************
package Assignment_1;

public class BanffMarathonRunner extends AddressBook {

 // Member variables
 private int time;
 private int years;
  
 // Constructors
 
 public BanffMarathonRunner(String firstName, String lastName, int min, int yr) {
  super(firstName, lastName);
  time = min;
  years = yr;  
 
 }
  
 // Getters and Setters
 
 public int getTime() {
  return time;
 }
 
 public void setTime(int time) {
  this.time = time;
 }
 
 public int getYears() {
  return years;
 }
 
 public void setYears(int years) {
  this.years = years;
 }

}
************************************************************

package Assignment_1;

import Assignment_1.BanffMarathonRunner;

public class TestBanffMarathonRunner {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 
  BanffMarathonRunner r1 = new BanffMarathonRunner("Elena", "Brandon", 341, 1);

  System.out.print(r1.getLastName());
      
 }

}
}
```

Comment: Your call to `super(firstName, lastName)` is calling the only constructor you defined with two arguments: the one that sets the first name and the middle name, not the last name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BanffMarathonRunner r1 = new BanffMarathonRunner("Elena", "Brandon", 341, 1);
```

calls:

```
// firstName = "Elena"
// lastName = "Brandon"
// min = 341
// yr = 1
public BanffMarathonRunner(String firstName, String lastName, int min, int yr) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
    // ...
}
```

which calls via `super(...)`:

```
// firstName = "Elena"
// middleName = "Brandon" <-- here is your issue
public AddressBook(String firstName, String middleName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
```

`Brandon` is set in `AddressBook#middleName` instead of `AddressBook#lastName`.

Comment: This also solved the issue and I gave it a check mark as it fully explained the process taking place. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Because `lastName` is null.

You are calling `AddressBook(String firstName, String middleName)`

and setting the `middleName`, not the `lastName`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the BanffMarathonRunner.java:

in the constructor when you are calling the

```
super(firstName, lastName);
```

Actually by the call above the super class constructor with two parameter is being called, and that constructor is the one which set the middleName not the lastName.

I think you are confused because of the `lastName` variable name, which is passed to the constructor with two argument and that constructor use the second argument to set the middleName.

Good Luck.

Comment: That's exactly what confused me. Thanks for your help.